# CvInvoke.ConvexityDefects() in EmguCV 3.0

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv, opencv3.0

I have a problem to specify the type of variables for ConvexityDefects in EmguCv 3.0 .

I can't find a replacement for Vec4i to declare "defects".

`VectorOfVectorOfInt defects = new VectorOfVectorOfInt()` -> This is just another attempt to find the appropriate type.

Every time I have a fatal error:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
No suitable directory found to load unmanaged modules
Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.dll

and the program moves me here, to line with CvException:

```
      private static int CvErrorHandler(
         int status,
         IntPtr funcName,
         IntPtr errMsg,
         IntPtr fileName,
         int line,
         IntPtr userData)
      {
         try
         {
            SetErrStatus(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ErrorCodes.StsOk); //clear the error status
            return 0; //signal the process to continue
         }
         finally
         {
            String funcNameStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(funcName);
            String errMsgStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errMsg);
            String fileNameStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(fileName);
            throw new CvException(status, funcNameStr, errMsgStr, fileNameStr, line);
         }
      }
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Part of my code:

```
using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
                        {
```

CvInvoke.FindContours(grayImg, contours, null, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
                        int count = contours.Size;
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        {
                            using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i])
                            using (VectorOfVectorOfInt defects = new VectorOfVectorOfInt())
                            using (VectorOfPoint approxContour = new VectorOfPoint())
                            using (VectorOfPoint hull = new VectorOfPoint())
                            { 
                                CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(contour, approxContour, 50, true);
                                CvInvoke.ConvexHull(contour, hull, false);
                                CvInvoke.Polylines(openCvImg, hull, true, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 1, LineType.AntiAlias);
                                CvInvoke.ConvexityDefects(contour, hull, defects);
                            }
                            largest_contour_index = i;
                        }
                        CvInvoke.DrawContours(openCvImg, contours, largest_contour_index, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 1, LineType.EightConnected);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

I had  exactly the same problem... I found solution in EmguCv unit tests (Unit Tests are often your best documentation)
The test is named TestConvexityDefacts and is in file AutoTestVarious in project Emgu.CV.Test 
Here is to link (but it is not official repo)
[EmguCv Test file](http://sourceforge.net/u/ecurien/emgucv/ci/5b35771b3eff459fe871390ceb4a525bfaa6e882/tree/Emgu.CV.Test/AutoTestVarious.cs#l301)

Official repo is here: git://git.code.sf.net/p/emgucv/code emgucv

The solution is to use Mat, as IOutputArray. Getting data from it is not so easy ;/ But this unit test will help.

Be aware, that from matrix you will get indexes of points. To get point coordinates, you need to use this index on contour vector of points.

Matrix has 3 columns - start point, end point and farthest point.

Also I had problem with hull VectorOfPoint as input in ConvexityDefects - I had to change it to VectorOfInt - if I didn't ConvexityDefects method was throwing some exception...